# How to find out the number of open windows in an application under test

Tags: c#, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm using coded ui to do my automation I need to count how many windows open for a test case but have no idea how to do it. Have tried using find and getting the applicationundertest and walking the childrens but seems like the windows don't belong to it.

Anyone got experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most UI frameworks have a collection of the open windows.

Winforms:

```
int count = Application.OpenForms.Count;
```

> A FormCollection containing all the currently open forms owned by this
>   application.

WPF:

```
 int count = Application.Current.Windows.Count;
```

> A Window reference is automatically added to Windows as soon as a
>   window is instantiated on the user interface (UI) thread; windows that
>   are created by worker threads are not added. A Window reference is
>   automatically removed after its Closing event has been handled and
>   before its Closed event is raised.

Comment: My question is regarding how to do it using the codedui automation framework.  This works inside the application but not from coded ui since it gives the window of what is currently running. Let me know if im missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a static int in your main instance and count it up in all forms constructors and down in FormClosing event

Maybe this short code will be helpfull

```
this.Load += delegate { mainInstance.myCount++; };
this.FormClosing += delegate { mainInstance.myCount--; };
```

Comment: Since this is for testing, I would hook the Load event on the form instead of adding to the constructor.